# Pyserial read empty b'' from COM port

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, readline, pyserial

I'm testing my COM port cuz I need to read streaming data from a radar board by python.

First, I wrote a arduino code like below figure.
[image]

It generate number continuously.

And wrote the pyserial:

```
import serial
import time, os

ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_ODD, rtscts=0)

if (ser.isOpen() == True):
    print ("Port:",ser.port)
    #input = input(">> ")
    #input = b"p"

    ser.write(b'1\n\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    numOfLines = 0
    while 1:
        #if (ser.inWaiting()>0):
        response = ser.readline()
        print (response)
    
        numOfLines +=1
        if numOfLines>10:
            break
    ser.close()
```

But I got the result:
[image]

If I run the arduino serial output window before I compile my python code, I will get the output correctly.(like b'193\n', b'194\n'...), or I'll get nothing.(b'').

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my processing?

Comment: First, the protocol between arduino and pyserial(in PC?) Is not clear. Please specify both prerequisites, initial state, processing sequence, termination condition etc in communication.
It is to make a program based on that. Besides, the displayed arduino code is insufficient. To ask a question, please display the whole program. It seems that the arduino side program has ended for some reason or is not transmitting.

Comment: @kunif Yes, pyserial is in PC. Actually, above is all of my arduino code. I use it to generate numbers or characters to test rx and tx.